# Is it possible to submit a domain to multiple security filters (so it isn't 'uncategorized'), or is there a checklist of the most popular ones?

Tags: security, url, web, dns

I was in a coffee shop this morning and found that our website was blocked by Fortinet security filter because it was 'uncategorized'.

I contacted Fortinet and the category has been changed which lifted the block.

I was wondering if anyone had a useful workflow, checklist, or method for ensuring that a domain isn't uncategorized on the most popular security filters?

Comment: I think this is a good question, but it should probably be on [Security SE](http://security.stackexchange.com/) as it is not really related to programming. OTOH it's not strictly a security question either.